# Разработка собственного АПИ для работы с БД

Tags: ios, android, php, java, mysql

Всем добрый день.
Есть задумка реализации некоего проекта, схожего по функционалу с социальными сетями, но доступная только на мобильных платформах Android и iOS.

Есть опыт работы с данными платформами, в том числе разработка клиент серверных приложений с АПИ JSON и XML, но вот разработкой собственного АПИ никогда не сталкивался, поэтому меня интересую все стороны данного вопроса. Попробую разбить его на несколько пунктов.

1. Правила и требования при создании базы данных, в которой хранится информация начиная от строк и заканчивая изображениями, музыкой и видео.
2. Написание АПИ с возможность по запросу считывания определенной информации с БД
3. Написание АПИ с возможностью изменения данных в БД или добавления информации(медиа файлы, информация о пользователе и т.д.)
4. Каким образом в мобильных социальных сетях организованна переписка с расширенным функционалом(приложения типа Вибера или Вотсапа)
5. Требования к безопасноти
6. Рекомендации по использованию языка и среды для разработки данного АПИ(возможно ли это сделать на JAVA, если да - то какие технологии и IDE)

Буду рад услышать ваши советы и рекомендации. Может есть подобные проекты с открытыми исходниками, статьи, примеры, документация? Чем больше информации тем круче.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: 1 - Изображения и музыку наверное плохо в БД хранить, лучше хранить путь к оным, а хранить например в WebDav
2 - На самом мобильном устройстве держать обращения к БД не стоит
3 - Посмотрите в сторону REST или SOAP и пр...
4 - Пока ничео сказать не могу
5 - Что значит требования к безопасности?...безопасность сессйи, шифромания или что Вы имеете ввиду?
6 - ну если андроид/IOS то наверное java

Т.е. само клиентское ЯП должно описывать взаимодействие с сервером, а сервер уже должен заниматься обработкой

Comment: Спасибо. Меня на сегодня больше всего интересует создание собственного АПИ.

Comment: смотря что понимать под разработкой api ? если просто организация то рекомендую изучить api контакта и подготовить подобие документации и  по ней уже писать

Answer (score 4):

1. База данных... Выбор инструмента начинаем с ответов на вопросы: сколько будет клиентов? Что, кроме профилей клиентов будем хранить и как долго? Какое соотношение операций чтения/записи ожидается для каждого вида данных? Будет ли необходимость в аналитических выборках (статистика в различных разрезах и т.п.)? Если данных ожидается много (10 млн записей в месяц и выше) и если аналитика не слишком важна - смотрим в сторону NoSQL (MongoDB и т.п.). Кстати, Mongo замечательно хранит файлы. И обязательно думаем над масштабированием и предусматриваем для "быстрых данных" какой-нибудь механизм кеширования, нарпрмер на базе Redis.
2. API... Перед проектированием протокола отвечаем на вопросы: будут ли события инициироваться только клиентом или сервером тоже? Важно ли экономить трафик? Заряд батареи? Допустима ли задержка при доставке уведомлений клиенту и на сколько? Насколько чувствительна конфиденциальность передаваемых данных (например, можем ли мы доверить доставку оповещений третьей стороне)? Вариантов тут множество, от обычных http rest запросов с клиента на сервер, long pooling и websocket для постоянного двустороннего соединения и до использования нового двунаправленного [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) или других сторонних инструментов доставки сообщений.
3. То же, что и 2. По поводу серверной реализации API... Думаем опять же о планируемой нагрузке, но уже в контексте числа коннектов в единицу времени. Сотню одновременных коннектов потянет почти любая платформа, если писать без глупостей. Тысячи - то, что хорошо масштабируется (например JavaEE), или python c его "читерскими" однопоточными серверами. Десятки тысяч - только erlang или совсем уже какая-нибудь экзотика. Вообще, если вы получаете в конце концов огромное число одновременно открытых соединений, то где-то в архитектуре вы просчитались. Переходим на асинхронные модели взаимодействия с клиентом и жизнь налаживается.
4. Тоже что и 2. Long pooling или websocket с оповещением через запасной канал (sms, Cloud Messaging) если клиент вышел из сети.
5. Https на уровне канала передачи. Необратимое шифрование паролей на уровне базы. Вообще, методик много, смотря какие риски считаем приоритетными.
6. Языки и технологии по большей части описаны выше. Кроме всех рекомендаций приведённых ранее одна, самая, на мой взгляд, важная. Выбираем те технологии, которыми владеем лучше всего, а из них - самые простые. Расширить простое API легко будет в процессе развития проекта, а что-то сделать с черезмерно сложным уже будет куда труднее и дороже.

Answer (score 0):

На сайте ibm.com много статей посвященных интересующей вас теме. Вот ссылка на серию статей http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/wa-jaxrs/